# How to validate a form with the help of javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created a registration form and i want to validate using javascript or jquery.

condition is its like ajax where we have to not submit the form untill all validations are correct.

here is my html code

```
<div><ul class="menusubnav">
<li class="orange"><a href="">Manager</a></li>
<li><a href="">New Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="">Edit Customer</a>
<li><a href="">Delete Customer</a></li>
<li><a href="newaccount.html">New Account</a></li>
<li><a href="">Edit Account</a></li>
<li><a href="">Delete Account</a></li>
</ul></div>
<table class="layout" border="0" width="50%" align="center">
<form name="addcust" method="post" action="" id="form1">
    <td colspan="2">
    <table border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><p class="maintitle">Add New Customer</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fontstyle">Customer Name<span></span></td>
            <td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fontstyle">Gender<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle">
                <input type ="radio" name ="rad1" value="1" checked>male</br>
                <input type ="radio" name ="rad1" value="1">female
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fontstyle">Date of Birth <span></span></td>
            <td class="fontstyle"> <select name ="day">
                <option value ="1">1</option>
                <option value ="2">2</option>
                <option value ="3">3</option>
                <option value ="4">4</option>
                <option value ="5">5</option>
                <option value ="6">6</option>
                <option value ="7">7</option>
                <option value ="8">8</option>
                <option value ="9">9</option>
                <option value ="10">10</option>
                <option value ="11">11</option>
                <option value ="12">12</option>
                <option value ="13">13</option>
                <option value ="14">14</option>
                <option value ="15">15</option>
                <option value ="16">16</option>
                <option value ="17">17</option>
                <option value ="18">18</option>
                <option value ="19">19</option>
                <option value ="20">20</option>
                <option value ="21">21</option>
                <option value ="22">22</option>
                <option value ="23">23</option>
                <option value ="24">24</option>
                <option value ="25">25</option>
                <option value ="26">26</option>
                <option value ="27">27</option>
                <option value ="28">28</option>
                <option value ="29">29</option>
                <option value ="30">30</option>
                <option value ="31">31</option>
            </select>
            <select name ="month">
                <option value ="1">JAN</option>
                <option value ="2">FEB</option>
                <option value ="3">MAR</option>
                <option value ="4">APR</option>
                <option value ="5">MAY</option>
                <option value ="6">JUN</option>
                <option value ="7">JUL</option>
                <option value ="8">AUG</option>
                <option value ="9">SEP</option>
                <option value ="10">OCT</option>
                <option value ="11">NOV</option>
                <option value ="12">DEC</option>
            </select>
            <select name ="year">
            <option value ="1980">1980</option>
            <option value ="1981">1981</option>
            <option value ="1982">1982</option>
            <option value ="1983">1983</option>
            <option value ="1984">1984</option>
            <option value ="1985">1985</option>
            <option value ="1986">1986</option>
            <option value ="1987">1987</option>
            <option value ="1988">1988</option>
            <option value ="1989">1989</option>
            <option value ="1990">1990</option>
            <option value ="1991">1991</option>
            <option value ="1992">1992</option>
            <option value ="1993">1993</option>
            <option value ="1994">1994</option>
            <option value ="1995">1995</option>
            <option value ="1996">1996</option>
            <option value ="1997">1997</option>
            <option value ="1998">1998</option>
            <option value ="1999">1999</option>
            <option value ="2000">2000</option>
            <option value ="2001">2001</option>
            <option value ="2002">2002</option>
            <option value ="2003">2003</option>
            <option value ="2004">2004</option>
            <option value ="2005">2005</option>
            <option value ="2006">2006</option>
            <option value ="2007">2007</option>
            <option value ="2008">2008</option>
            <option value ="2009">2009</option>
            <option value ="2010">2010</option>
            <option value ="2011">2011</option>
            <option value ="2012">2012</option>
            <option value ="2013">2013</option>
            <option value ="2014">2014</option>
            <option value ="2015">2015</option>
            <option value ="2016">2016</option>
            <option value ="2017">2017</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">Address<span></span></td>
    <td class="fontstyle">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="addr" maxlength="50"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">City<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="city" maxlength="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">State<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="state" maxlength="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">PIN<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">Telephone Number<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="tel" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">Fax<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="fax" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">E-mail<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="fontstyle">User Id<span></span></td><td class="fontstyle"><input type="text" name="uid" maxlength="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td class="fontstyle"></td>
        <td class="fontstyle"><input type ="Submit" value ="Submit" name ="sub" onClick="validate();" class = "button">
        <input type ="reset" value ="Reset" name ="res" class = "button"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<p align="right"><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></p>
```

and here is my jscript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form#form1 .submit').click(function(){

        $('#form1 .error').hide();  //if error visibile, hide on new click

        var name = $('input#name').val();
         var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
        if (name == "" || name == " " ) {
            $('input#name').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you name!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(name.value.match(numbers)){
             $('input#name').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you name!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var addr = $('input#addr').val();
        if (addr == "" || addr == " " ) {
            $('input#addr').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you Address!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var city = $('input#city').val();
        if (city == "" || city == " " ) {
            $('input#city').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you city!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(city.value.match(numbers)){
             $('input#city').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you city!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var state = $('input#state').val();
        if (state == "" || state == " " ) {
            $('input#state').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you state!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(state.value.match(numbers)){
             $('input#state').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you state!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var pin = $('input#pin').val();
        var pincode = /^\d{10}$/; 
        if (pin == "" || pin == " " ) {
            $('input#pin').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you pinncode!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(pin.value.match(pincode)){
             return true;
        }else{
            $('input#pin').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you pincode!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var tel = $('input#tel').val();
        var telephone = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/; 
        if (tel == "" || tel == " " ) {
            $('input#tel').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you telephone number!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(tel.value.match(telephone)){
             return true;
        }else{
            $('input#tel').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you telephone number!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var email_test = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
        var email = $('input#email').val();
        if (email == "" || email == " ") {
           $('input#email').focus().before('<div class="error">Psst. You missed one.</div>');
           return false;
        } else if (!email_test.test(email)) {
           $('input#email').select().before('<div class="error">I think your email is wrong...</div>');
           return false;
        }

        var message = $('#message').val();
        if (message == "" || message == " " || message == "Message") {
            $('#message').focus().fadeIn('slow').before('<div class="error">Oops! You forgot to type a message!</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var data_string = $('form#form1').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type:       "POST",
            url:        "email.php",
            data:       data_string,
            success:    function() {

        $('form#form1').slideUp('fast').before('<div id="success"></div>');
        $('#success').html('<h3>Success</h3><p>Your email has been sent.</p>').slideDown(9000);

            }//end success function


        }) //end ajax call

        return false;


    }) //end click function

    var current_data = new Array();

    $('.clear').each(function(i){
        $(this).removeClass('clear').addClass('clear'+i);
        current_data.push($(this).val());

        $(this).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == current_data[i]) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            var stored_data = current_data[i];
            if($(this).val()==''){
                $(this).val(stored_data);
            }
        })
    });
})
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akkL3/)
Please give me suggestions where I am wrong, please help.

Comment: best pluginfor javascript validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Okie can you say me how to install and use that plugin step by step or provide me the link where it is simple to understand thoroughky.

Comment: Can you give details of exactly why your code does not work.

Comment: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ see in this all the demo given beginner to advance it will helpful

Comment: And I would prefer it if you cut down your code to a minimum which just exposes the problem. So no endless list of options. Otherwise we have a "finish my code please" request and not a problem of general interest.

Comment: reduce my code.please check-$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('form#form1 .submit').click(function(){

  $('#form1 .error').hide(); //if error visibile, hide on new click
  
  var name = $('input#name').val();
   var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
  if (name == "" || name == " " ) {
      $('input#name').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you name!?</div>');
      return false;
  }else if(name.value.match(numbers)){
    $('input#name').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you name!?</div>');
      return false;
 });
})and my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/akkL3/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check this updated fiddle**: **http://jsfiddle.net/akkL3/1/**

See, there are a lot of problems with your code. However to start simple, here are a couple of basic ones:

***First:***

If you are using "name" like this in your code:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Then the selector should be `$('input[name="name"]').val();`

Better still, you should be using `id`'s like this:

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

Then the selector can remain `$('input#name').val();`

***Second:***

You are declaring your submit button like this:

```
<input type ="Submit" value ="Submit" name ="sub" onclick="validate();"...
```

and then you are binding the `click` unobtrusively also!

```
$('form#form1 .submit').click(function(){...
```

You have to use one approach, preferably unobtrusive. However, to keep things simple here, lets remove the unobtrusive binding. So, it becomes a `validate` function instead:

```
function validate() { ...
```

And then, you need to return it in the inline `onclick` handler:

```
<input type ="Submit" value ="Submit" onclick="return validate()" ...
```

Just these couple of changes will get your code working. **However**, you need more work to go forward from here.

Comment: Will you please do it in my jsfiddle because i am new to the jquery as well as jscript please help..

Comment: @SanjayRathod , the updated fiddle in my answer above is your fiddle only. Just the couple of changes described above. Otherwise the fiddle is yours only.

Comment: Whay i had to do if i want to do for onBlur event?your code is working thanking you

Answer (score 1):

I think the submit is going first and the click in second place.

Maybe if you change in the HTML the input type of the submit to button and inside de js submit the form  with jquery (.submit()) when the validation is ok.

Comment: can you do this in jsfiddle.because i dont understand what are you talking about

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of mistakes in your html.

1) there is no class **`submit`** in submit button.

```
<input type ="Submit" value ="Submit" name ="sub" onClick="validate();" class = "button">

$('form#form1 .submit').click(function(){  // So this will never hapen
```

2) the is no id called **`name`**

```
<input type="text" name="name">
var name = $('input#name').val();  //This won't work
```

Similar mistakes in all attributes.

Better approach

1) Use [**`.submit()`**](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) like

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
```

2) Move to some validation plugins like [**jQuery validation**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) or [**validaionEngine**](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#form1").submit(function(){   
        $('#form1 .error').hide();  //if error visibile, hide on new click
         var name = $('input#name').val();
         var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
         if (name == "" || name == " " ) {
            $('input#name').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you name!?</div>');
         return false;
        }else if(name.value.match(numbers)){
             $('input#name').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you name!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var addr = $('input#addr').val();
        if (addr == "" || addr == " " ) {
            $('input#addr').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you Address!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var city = $('input#city').val();
        if (city == "" || city == " " ) {
            $('input#city').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you city!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(city.value.match(numbers)){
             $('input#city').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you city!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var state = $('input#state').val();
        if (state == "" || state == " " ) {
            $('input#state').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you state!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(state.value.match(numbers)){
             $('input#state').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you state!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var pin = $('input#pin').val();
        var pincode = /^\d{10}$/; 
        if (pin == "" || pin == " " ) {
            $('input#pin').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you pinncode!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(pin.value.match(pincode)){
             return true;
        }else{
            $('input#pin').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you pincode!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var tel = $('input#tel').val();
        var telephone = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/; 
        if (tel == "" || tel == " " ) {
            $('input#tel').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you telephone number!?</div>');
            return false;
        }else if(tel.value.match(telephone)){
             return true;
        }else{
            $('input#tel').focus().before('<div class="error">Hey, what is you telephone number!?</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var email_test = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
        var email = $('input#email').val();
        if (email == "" || email == " ") {
           $('input#email').focus().before('<div class="error">Psst. You missed one.</div>');
           return false;
        } else if (!email_test.test(email)) {
           $('input#email').select().before('<div class="error">I think your email is wrong...</div>');
           return false;
        }

        var message = $('#message').val();
        if (message == "" || message == " " || message == "Message") {
            $('#message').focus().fadeIn('slow').before('<div class="error">Oops! You forgot to type a message!</div>');
            return false;
        }

        var data_string = $('form#form1').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type:       "POST",
            url:        "email.php",
            data:       data_string,
            success:    function() {

        $('form#form1').slideUp('fast').before('<div id="success"></div>');
        $('#success').html('<h3>Success</h3><p>Your email has been sent.</p>').slideDown(9000);

            }//end success function


        }) //end ajax call

}); 

and remove validate function from submit btn and check id of inputs.
```

Comment: Will you please do it in my jsfiddle because i am new to the jquery as well as jscript please help..

Answer (score 0):

If i was you i would just use html5 validation and have a serverside validation fallback for browsers that dont support native html5 validation. You should always have a server side validation fallback anyway as its way too easy to bypass javascript validation.

Use html5 validation by simply adding the attribute

```
required="required"
```

to your input fields and the browser will do the rest for you.

Failing that you really should stop the form submitting by default and then only submit it if all conditions are met rather than the other way round.

Ie

```
//On submit of the form
$("form").submit(function(e){

    //stop the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    //set an error var
    var error = false;

    //perform your checks here
    //ie
    var val = $(this).find("input[name='name']").val();
    if(val == ""){
        var error = true;
    }

    //if there are no errors then submit the form
    if(!errors){

        //only chose one of the next two options

        //option 1 - submit normally
        $(this).submit();

        //option 2 - submit via ajax
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            data         : data,
            dataType     : "json",
            url          : "url you want to submit to",
            type         : "post",
            success      : function(response){
                 console.log(response);
            },
            error        : function(a,b,c){
                 console.log(a,b,c);
            }
        });

    }else{
        //there have been errors so tell the user in some way
    }

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will you please do it in my jsfiddle because i am new to the jquery as well as jscript please help..